# Java EE, JSF programmaticaly login with form-based does not redirect to user's home page on production

Tags: authentication, web.xml, payara, java-ee-8

I'm developping a project with several different user profiles / roles. Security is realm-based and a form authentications is used. When a user logs in successfuly it must be redirected to his/her home page according tho the user's role.

All those things are working perfectly on my developping environment. I'm using Netbeans IDE with Payara 5 application server runtime.

To put a beta version on production I've used an Ubuntu machine where I've installed Payara 5 full version. After that (server configuration, realm, jdbc connection, ...) I've realized that when a user logs in successfully and it is redirected to his/her home page the login form is presented again and user can't access to his home-page.

Here is an extract of my web.xml file:

```
        <servlet>
            <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
            <servlet-class>javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet</servlet-class>
            <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
        </servlet>    
        <servlet-mapping>
            <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
            <url-pattern>*.xhtml</url-pattern>
        </servlet-mapping>    
        <welcome-file-list>
            <welcome-file>index.xhtml</welcome-file>
        </welcome-file-list>
       <login-config>
            <auth-method>FORM</auth-method>
            <realm-name>MyRealmName</realm-name>
            <form-login-config>
                <form-login-page>/authentication/login.xhtml</form-login-page>
                <form-error-page>/authentication/error.xhtml</form-error-page>
            </form-login-config>
        </login-config>
        <security-constraint>
        <web-resource-collection>
            <web-resource-name>Admin portal</web-resource-name>
            <url-pattern>/subfolder/*</url-pattern>
        </web-resource-collection>
        <auth-constraint>
            <role-name>role_admin</role-name>
        </auth-constraint>
    </security-constraint>    
    <session-config>
        <session-timeout>
            5
        </session-timeout>
    </session-config>
```

To map group names with role names I've used this file 'glassfish-web.xml'

```
<glassfish-web-app>   
    <context-root>/WebAppDeplo</context-root>    
    <security-role-mapping>
        <role-name>role_admin</role-name>
        <group-name>ADMINISTRATOR</group-name>
    </security-role-mapping>  
</glassfish-web-app>
```

Finally, here's the code of login() method

```
private static String HOME = "/subfolder/index.xhtml?faces-redirect=true";

// ...

public void login() throws IOException {
        ExternalContext externalContext
                = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext();
        HttpServletRequest request = (HttpServletRequest) externalContext.getRequest();
        
        log.debug("[bean] - login()");
        
        try{
            request.login(this.userName, this.password);
            // Authentication OK
            String url = extractContextPath() + HOME;
            log.debug("[bean] - login() - login OK - redirecting to: " + url);
            externalContext.redirect(url);
        }catch (ServletException e){
            // Authentication failed
            log.debug("[bean] - login() - Authentication failed!");
            String loginErrorMessage = e.getLocalizedMessage();
            FacesContext.getCurrentInstance()
                    .addMessage(null, new FacesMessage(loginErrorMessage));
        }
    }

    private String extractContextPath() {
        ExternalContext externalContext
                = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext();
        return externalContext.getRequestContextPath();
    }
```

Several thoughts:

a) Using a BASIC authentication on web.xml. It works fine! Unfortunately, programatically login is required because different user roles must be loged and redirectet to role-based home-page.

b) Authentication mechanism works fine because if a wrong login is entered the ServletException is thrown. When a right user is provided the debug message "[bean] - login() - login OK..." is printed in the log file. No other errors seen on log file.

c) I've tried several values of static variable HOME: "/subfolder", "/subforlder/index", ... All this options work fine on developping environment but not on production environment.

d) I've tried Payara 5.201 and Payara 5 5.2021.3 to avoid specific version server bugs.

e) What is upsetting me is the fact that on developing environment this thing works fine! :-(

I appreciate any ideas you can throw on this matter.

Answer (score 0):

I'm auto responding my question because I guess I've already found an important clue to address this issue.
I've realized that when accessing to production deployment a session cookie is not created in browser.
So, I've found a parameter in web.xml that permits to customize session cookie's name.
Typing this parameter authentication (form-based, and redirecting to user home-page) works fine.
Here is the slice of web.xml affected:

```
    <session-config>
        <session-timeout>5</session-timeout>
         <cookie-config>
            <name>MY_JSESSIONID</name>
        </cookie-config>
    </session-config>
```